# Conditions for adding database to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to mysql, I wrote this php script which make a new row in mysql database table and it works fine but it add this row regardless of its existence. what I need is my script to check the "username" column in the table if we dont have such a username add the whole row into the table, if we have such a username just update "Minutes" column. Thanks in advance.

```
<?PHP

    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "12345i";
    $server = "localhost";
    $database = "maz_database";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO maz_table (Username,Password,Email_address,Address,Minutes,Tags) VALUES('maz','pass','maz@yahoo.com','london',2000,'')";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    mysql_close($db_handle);
    print "Records added to the database";

    }
    else {

    print "Database NOT Found ";
    mysql_close($db_handle);

    }

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: If you wish to check if a row exists, use `mysql_num_rows()` - Plus, if you want to avoid duplicates, set your column(s) type to `UNIQUE` <= done deal ;-)

Comment: Thanks Fred, I should first look at those statements to see how they work.This is my second day working with mysql.

Comment: You're welcome. As `esqew` suggested, you're better off using `mysqli_` or PDO libraries, unless you really want or must use `mysql_`. It's always best working with up-to-date stuff ;-) plus, it's more secure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to specify what to do when the record already exists.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO maz_table (Username,Password,Email_address,Address,Minutes,Tags) 
VALUES ('maz','pass','maz@yahoo.com','london',2000,'')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Minutes = $minutesvariable
```

Where Username is your Primary Key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael, do I need if else statement or if not exists statement to achieve this? what should I do with minutes variable? sorry I have very basic knowledge of this.

Comment: You do not need an else because you are telling it to insert the values and if the values already exist, then just update it.

See this page for how to use variables: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp